# API Platform: Can't get using a json data type with MySQL to work

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm new to the API Platform and trying to get a json data attribute to persist to MySQL as a json object. I've looked over the API Platform documentation and googled for an answer, but didn't find anything that answers this.

My setup:

MySQL column is defined as:

```
`document` json DEFAULT NULL
```

I've defined a "MyEntity" PHP object and the json attribute is described as follows:

```
/**
 * @var json 
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $document;

/**
 * Get document.
 *
 * @return json
 */
public function getDocument()
{
    return $this->document;
}

/**
 * Set document.
 *
 * @param json $document
 *
 * @return MyEntity
 */
public function setDocument($document)
{
    $this->document = $document;

    return $this;
}
```

Now when up that URL that shows the default interface for MyEntity and execute a POST to create it using this json-ld (simplifying to leave out other columns):

```
{
    "document": "{"test": "value"}"
}
```

I get a 400 Bad Request Error

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Syntax error",
    "trace": [
    {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/Library/WebServer/Documents/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/JsonDecode.php",
        "line": 78,
        "args": []
    },
...
```

I escaped the double quotes (which seems strange to me that it you would need to do this since it is a json itself that is describing another json object) like this:

```
{
    "document": "{\"test\": \"value\"}"
}
```

and execute a POST again:

I get a 400 Bad Request Error with a different internal error:

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Could not denormalize object of type AppBundle\\Entity\\json, no supporting normalizer found.",
    "trace": [
    {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/Library/WebServer/Documents/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.php",
       "line": 295,
       "args": []
    },  
...
```

So it look like API Platform doesn't recognize the JSON data type and is expecting a custom entity for it...doesn't seem right to me.

I've also looked at types for doctrine, which in my understanding, API Platform uses and found this info:

> Some vendors have a native JSON type and Doctrine will use it if
>   possible and otherwise silently fall back to the vendor’s text type to
>   ensure the most efficient storage requirements. If the vendor does not
>   have a native JSON type, this type requires an SQL column comment hint
>   so that it can be reverse engineered from the database. Doctrine
>   cannot map back this type properly on vendors not supporting column
>   comments and will fall back to text type instead.

But since MySQL does support a JSON data type, I thought this would just work, but apparently not. Any help on how API Platform works with a JSON data type using MYSQL would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does Doctrine know about MySQL 5.7's JSON data type?

Comment: I googled around and found this link: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2266, which indicates to me that it now does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because of your PHPdoc type hints. Api-platform uses PHPdoc metadata during normalization.

There is no such things as "json" data type in PHP, so it will look for a class in the same namespace.

From Doctrine documentation:

> Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP’s array or null types using PHP’s json_decode() function.

So you should change your PHPDoc typehint to `array`

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $document;

/**
 * Get document.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getDocument()
{
    return $this->document;
}

/**
 * Set document.
 *
 * @param array $document
 *
 * @return MyEntity
 */
public function setDocument($document)
{
    $this->document = $document;

    return $this;
}
```